# Convert a (String, List[(String, String)]) to JSON object

Tags: scala, apache-spark-1.6

I have the data as:

```
(ID001,List((BookType,[text]),(author,xyz abc),(time,01/12/2019[22:00] CST/PM))),(ID002,List((BookType,[text]),(author,klj fgh),(time,19/02/2019[12:00] CST/AM)))
```

I need to convert this to a JSON object:

```
{"ID001":{
    "BookType":"[text]",
    "author":"xyz abc",
    "time":"01/12/2019[22:00] CST/PM" 
    },
{"ID002": {
    "BookType":"[text]" , 
    "author":"klj fgh", 
    "time":"19/02/2019[12:00] CST/AM"
    } 
}
```

I am very new to Scala Spark. Any idea how to convert this.

Comment: is this data in Dataframe? could you the code snippet you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating the json use the jackson which has got good utilities.In your case the following done can be using the below code

```
      val mapper = new ObjectMapper`
      val data = ("ID01", List(("BookType", "[text]"),("author", "xyz abc"),"time","01/12/2019[22:00] CST/PM")))
      val id = mapper.createObjectNode()
      val bookDetails = mapper.createObjectNode()
      data._2.foreach(x => {bookDetails.put(x._1, x._2)})
      id.set(data._1, bookDetails)
      println(id.toString)
```

The output of the above will be as follows

> `{"ID01":{"BookType":"[text]","author":"xyz abc","time":"01/12/2019[22:00] CST/PM"}}`